# JSP Nullpointer Exception when HashMap.keySet()

Tags: java, database, tomcat, concurrenthashmap

I have a very annoying problem.

I have developed a website with JSP and everything works perfectly on my local PC when I run it in Netbeans.

But if I put it on my Tomcat 7 server, one page gets an Null Pointer Exception at the line hsFilter.keySet():

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, LinkedList<String>> hsFilter = (ConcurrentHashMap<String, LinkedList<String>>) session.getAttribute("hashMap_typ");
Set<String> set = hsFilter.keySet();
Iterator it = set.iterator();
```

The Tomcat log says the following:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.jsp.jsp.dynamisch_005fmitglieder_jsp._jspService(dynamisch_005fmitglieder_jsp.java:947)    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
>     at Servlet.MainServlet.doPost(MainServlet.java:137)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

The really crazy thing is that the page gets loaded half way through and breaks in the middle.
If I log in as admin everything works but if I login as user it gets a NPE.

I hope someone can help me because I'm really new into JSP.

Greets

Comment: `hsFilter` has a `null` value. Check why that may happen.

Comment: attribute "hashMap_typ" does not exists thus a null value for hsFilter

Comment: i checked it already and it isn't null.
If i login as Admin everything works but if I login as a user it gets null. On the page there is no difference between admin and user